# iPhone Proxy auto-configuration with username / password

Tags: iphone, proxy

I'm looking for a way to include the username and password to an auto configurated setting for proxies on iOS. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP GET logins have you include your username and password in the URL. For example, if you're using the fictional proxy that's located at `www.an-example-proxy.com/proxy-login`, and you were instructed to use port `3333`, and your username is `foo`, and your password is `bar`, then you would put `http://foo:bar@www.an-example-proxy.com:3333/proxy-login` in the `URL` field on the `Auto` tab under `Settings > WiFi > ESSID (Network Name) > HTTP Proxy` (this doesn't sound too much like an automatically configured proxy to me, though, but this should get you logged on).